# Get Related Records Fails

Tags: phalcon

I'm having some trouble getting the Phalcon ORM to load related records.  A simple example with some code truncated for brevity:  Can anyone tell me why calls to related tables "forget" the foreign key from the parent table?

For a given table **Users**, there can be many **UserAddrs**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    .....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `password_UNIQUE` (`password`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2806 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and../

```
CREATE TABLE `user_addrs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_user_addrs_users1_idx` (`users_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_addrs_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

/models/Users.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany("id", "PhalconRest\Models\UserAddrs", "users_id", array('alias' => 'UserAddrs'));
```

/models/UserAddrs.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->belongsTo('users_id', 'PhalconRest\Models\Users', 'id', array('alias' => 'Users'));
```

This code....

```
    $user = Users::findFirst($id);
    $userAddrsRecs = $user->UserAddrs->toArray();
```

Gets me...

```
SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 103 LIMIT :1

SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='user_addrs'

DESCRIBE `user_addrs`

SELECT `user_addrs`.`id` FROM `user_addrs` WHERE `user_addrs`.`users_id` = :0
```

**Question: Why does the call to user_addrs forget that the related record was for users.id 103?**

Comment: I don't see where it loses it: `WHERE user_addrs.users_id = :0` clearly means that it binds something, most probably the 103 value you're talking about.

Comment: You are correct, though to a Phalcon Newb, 
   users_id = :0     meant nothing to me at the time.

Comment: Just to be clear (for other readers): binding is done at the PDO level, not by Phalcon. You can see many forms: `?`, `?0`,`:0`, `:id`, `:id:` (numeric versus named binding).